# Python MySQL queue: run code/queries in parallel, but commit separately

Tags: python, mysql

Program 1 inserts some jobs into a table job_table.

Program 2 needs to :

```
1. get the job from the table
2. handle the job
   -> this needs to be multi-threaded (because each job involves urllib waiting time, which should run in parallel)
3. insert the results into my_other_table, commiting the result
```

Any good (standard?) ways to implement this? The issue is that commiting inside one thread, also commits the other threads.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to pick the records from the mysql table and put them in queue later get them from queue but not able to insert into a new mysql table.

Here i am able to pick up only the new records when ever they fall into the table.
Hope this may help you.
Any mistakes please assist me.

```
from threading import Thread
import time
import Queue
import csv
import random
import pandas as pd
import pymysql.cursors
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import logging

queue = Queue.Queue(1000)

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='(%(threadName)-9s) %(message)s', )

conn = pymysql.connect(conn-details)
cursor = conn.cursor()


class ProducerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global queue
        cursor.execute("SELECT ID FROM multi ORDER BY ID  LIMIT 1")
        min_id = cursor.fetchall()
        min_id1 = list(min_id[0])
        while True:
            cursor.execute("SELECT ID FROM multi ORDER BY ID desc LIMIT 1")
            max_id = cursor.fetchall()
            max_id1 = list(max_id[0])
            sql = "select * from multi where ID between '{}' and '{}'".format(min_id1[0], max_id1[0])
            cursor.execute(sql)
            data = cursor.fetchall()
            min_id1[0] = max_id1[0] + 1
            for row in data:
                num = row
                queue.put(num)  # acquire();wait()
                logging.debug('Putting ' + str(num) + ' : ' + str(queue.qsize()) + ' items in queue')


class ConsumerThread(Thread):
    def run(self):
        global queue
        while True:
            num = queue.get()
            print num
            logging.debug('Getting ' + str(num) + ' : ' + str(queue.qsize()) + ' items in queue')
            **sql1 = """insert into multi_out(ID,clientname) values ('%s','%s')""",num[0],num[1]
            print sql1
            # cursor.execute(sql1, num)
            cursor.execute("""insert into multi_out(ID,clientname) values ('%s','%s')""",(num[0],num[1]))**
            # conn.commit()
            # conn.close()
def main():
    ProducerThread().start()
    num_of_consumers = 20
    for i in range(num_of_consumers):
        ConsumerThread().start()


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

What probably happens is you share the MySQL connection between the two threads. Try creating a new MySQL connection inside each thread.

For program 2, look at http://www.celeryproject.org/ :)

Comment: So yo think it should be possible to have the threads be completely independent with respect to the connection?

Comment: Yes, I do not know how you create the MySQL Connection, but each thread should create it's own when starting instead of re-using a shared object.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common task when doing some sort of web crawling. I have implemented a single thread which grabs a job, waits for the http response, then writes the response to a database table.

The problems I have come across with my method, is you need to lock the table where you are grabbing jobs from, and mark them as in progress or complete, in order for multiple threads to not try and grab the same task.

Just used threading.Thread in python and override the run method.

Use 1 database connection per thread. (some db libraries in python are not thread safe)

Answer (score 0):

If you have X number of threads running, periodically reading from the jobs table then MySQL will do the concurrency for you. 
Or if you need even more assurance, you can always lock the jobs table yourself before reading the next available entry. This way you can be 100% sure that a single job will only be processed once.

As @Martin said, keep connections separate for all threads. They can use the same credentials.

So in short:

1. Program one -> Insert into jobs
2. Program two -> Create a write lock on the jobs table, so no one else can read from it
3. Program two -> read next available job
4. Program two -> Unlock the table
5. Do everything else as usual, MySQL will handle concurrency